# Severity of covering the hair for women

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, women, hair-covering

I've heard Rabbi Yaron Reuben saying women who do not wear *kisui rosh* (putting the dispute of wigs as an exception), are like a woman who sinned before her husband.  The Rabbi said that the *kohen* used to first warn about the consequences of drinking the '**Sotah Water'** and if she does not acknowledge, the *kohen* would then pull off the *kisui rosh* of the woman.

Can I please have a source for this?  And also,  what is the severity of leaving the hair of a married jewish women without a covering?

Comment: Why don't you ask that rabbi in person? Remember, a lot of lectures are mostly educational, and not informative. Their sole purpose is to make people change their behavior, and not give them relevant information on the subject.

Comment: I understand. I was expecting at least for the Severity part

Comment: AFAIK, Kisuy Rosh is traditional and falls under Daas Yehudis. There's no explicit Mitzvah in that. See Mishnah Ksubos 7,6  וְאֵיזוֹהִי דַת יְהוּדִית, יוֹצְאָה וְרֹאשָׁהּ פָּרוּעַ, וְטוֹוָה בַשּׁוּק, וּמְדַבֶּרֶת עִם כָּל אָדָם. Such a woman can only lose her Kesubah, but nothing more severe.

Comment: Do we have any Kabbalistic view on it?

Comment: Kabbalistic is for Kabbalists. For the rest of the people there's Halachah. My advice, don't dive into Kabalah before learning the Gomorrah for at least 10 years.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Rav Moshe Feinstein wrote extensively about hair covering for women. Just look up שיער in the index of the Igros Moshe and you will find several articles about the subject. He rules that the uncovered hair of a married Jewish woman is ervah d'oraisa.

Comment: Regarding a source for removing *kisui rosh* from a *sotah*: it is an [explicit verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.5.18?lang=bi).

Comment: @shmu It's an erva toward others, but not for her, she can read Shmah while seeing her hair. So for her it's not a prohibition.

Comment: I am quite sure that also the rabbi quoted in the question was talking about uncovered hair in the presence of other men. In fact, Rav Feinstein draws a distinction between the ervah of uncovered hair and the ervah of uncovered flesh, but nevertheless, uncovered hair is judged as immodesty according to Biblical law.

Comment: Can I please have a clear cut answer?

Comment: The rabbi quoted in the question stated the case so strongly that it is hard to back it up. Most Halachic sources do not describe it in such extreme terms.

Comment: How about anything related?

Comment: “I heard... women who do not wear *kisui rosh* are like a woman who sinned before her husband.” I think this rabbi is loosely translating and applying to such a woman the term *[moredet](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/מורדת_על_בעלה)* (rebellious [wife]). A certified *moredet* looses her *ketuba* (“alimony”). However, a woman who does not cover her hair is termed *‘[overet al da’at yehudit](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.72a.9?with=all&lang=bi)* (transgresses Jewish custom). While the latter also forfeits her *ketubah* an OADY is not nec. halachically considered a *moredet*.

Comment: Please give those in the answers

Comment: @RhHaokip here is Kabbalah's view on hair in general: thttps://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380719/jewish/Mystical-Significance-of-Hair-Part-1.htm

Comment: @RhHaokip you might find this interesting too: https://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/2312434/jewish/Chapter-IV-Kissui-HaRosh-Hair-Covering.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bamidbar chapter 5 verse 18 states that the Kohen would pull off the woman's kisui rosh. Rashi there [explains](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9933/showrashi/true#v18) that from here we learn that a woman should have her hair covered. This is consistent with the Talmud's ruling (based on a Tannaic opinion) in [Kesubos 72a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.72a.19) that a married woman who does not cover her hair is transgressing a biblical commandment. I will also note that according to general opinion this is specifically referring to a married woman and only outside of her home (see Tosafot there).